# smart way to rewrite this function

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this, and I am showing a div if user clicked one button and not showing it if the user clicked other. Its working but its dumb to do this way with repeatition

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#Button1').click( function () { 
        var data = $j("form").serialize();
        $j.post('file.php', data, function(response){       
            $j("#Response").show();
        });
    });
    $j('#Button21').click( function () { 
        var data = $j("form").serialize();
        $j.post('file.php', data, function(response){       
            //do something else          

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it by adding a class to the selected buttons and then pull the `event.target` id from the click function:

```
    $j('.buttons').click(function(e) {
        var buttonId = e.target.id,
            data = $j("form").serialize();

        $j.post('file.php', data, function(response) {
            switch (buttonId) {
                case "Button1":
                    $j("#Response").show();
                    break;
                case "Button21":
                    //do something else
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't think detecting the target and using a switch statement is a good idea. This couples the behaviour to a specific dom style. You're assuming the dom elements have an ID. Also using a switch statement could quickly become unmanageable when you have 20+ items, each with a specific set of actions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to abstract the data from the functionality.

```
sendClick('#Button1', function() {
  $j('#Response').show();
});

sendClick('#Button21', function() {
  // do something
});
```

sendClick function

```
function sendClick(selector, callback)
{
  $j(selector).click( function () { 
    var data = $j("form").serialize();
    $j.post('file.php', data, callback);
  });
}
```

This way you can repeat the same functionality over and over by changing the selector and the callback. You could customise this even further by:

```
function sendClick(selector, options, callback)
{
  // handle arguments
  if(typeof options == 'function') { 
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  } else {
    options = options || {};
  }

  $j.extend({
    form: 'form',
    file: 'file.php'
  }, options);

  // abstracted logic
  $j(selector).click(function() { 
    var data = $j(options.form).serialize();
    $j.post(options.file, data, callback);
  });
}
```

then use like

```
sendClick('#select', {form: '#anotherForm'}, function() {
  // do something
});
```

or

```
sendClick('#another', function(response) {
  // something else
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways:

---

You can combine the two handlers into one handler:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#Button1, #Button21').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var data = $j("form").serialize();
        $j.post('file.php', data, function(response) {
            if (id == 'Button1') {
                // Show
            } else {
                // Do something else
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

Or write a special kind of handler:

```
$j.fn.clickAndPost = function (handler) {
    this.click(function () {
        var me = this;
        var data = $j("form").serialize();
        $j.post('file.php', data, function(response) {
            handler.call(me);
        });
    });
});
```

...and attach two of them:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#Button1').clickAndPost(function () {
        // Show
    });

    $j('#Button21').clickAndPost(function () {
        // Do something else
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the event to both, and then, when you need to check which element triggered the event, use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
$j(function() {
    $j('#Button1, #Button2').click( function (event) { 
        var data = $j("form").serialize();

         $j.post('file.php', data, function(response){       

             if ($(event.target).is('#Button1')) {
                 $j("#Response").show();
             } else {
                 // Do something else          
             }

         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$j(function($) {

    $('#Button1', '#Button21').click(function() {
        var that = this,
            data = $('form').serialize();

        $.post('file.php', data, function(response) {

            if ( that.id === 'Button1' ) {
                $('#Response').show();
            } else {
                //do something else   
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Button1 #Button21').click(function() {
        var that = this.attr("id");
            data = $('form').serialize();

        $.post('file.php', data, function(response) {

            if ( that === 'Button1' ) {
                $('#Response').show();
            } else {
                //do something else   
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Let me know if it's not working.